# How to pause render until the data is fetched in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am new to react, and I ran into this problem.

```js
import React from "react";
import firebase from "firebase";
import fire from "./firebase"
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Redirect, useHistory, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from "./header"
import Nav from "./nav"
import data from "./data"
function Home(){
    let userID;
    let userName;
    let logg;
    const history = useHistory();
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{
        if(user){
            userID = user.uid
        }else{
            history.push("/login")
        } 
    })
    
    return(
        <>
        <Header />
        <Nav />
        <div id = "home" className ="main">
            <div class = "headingCont">
                <h1>This is home</h1>
                <NavLink to = {"users/"+userID}><p>Your Profile</p></NavLink>
            </div>
        </div>
        </>
    )
    
}
export default Home
```

I am fetching user id from firebase, but it quickly renders the jsx, so the value of userID remains undefined. So, when I click on the Your Profile, it goes to user/undefined instead of user/"id of user"
how do i fix it?

Comment: You can show loader while loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use state for `userId` instead of scope variable.

```js
const [userID, setUserID] = useState(null)
```

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    setUserID(user.uid)
  } else {
    history.push('/login');
  }
});
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please tick my answer if it works.